# Largest file size for a JPEG file with a fixed resolution

Tags: jpeg

Is there a way to calculate the largest possible file size for a JPEG image with a fixed resolution?

For example, is it possible to say that a 1024x768 image has a maximum file size of 3MB?

Comment: You mean the largest possible size? It depends on the source image and the level of compression. Also, calculate where?

Comment: Yeah, the worst size is the maximum size, the worst compression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No there is not. It uses quantization matrices to try and reduce frequencies to 0, depending on how good that works, and how much of a pattern occurs for all these values, the compression becomes more efficient.

See [JPEG Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG), section *Codec Example* for more details on how the compression works. It should become clear from that that it is not possible.

Comment: Old question, but this has me curious as well. Couldn't the theoretical maximum be the same as an uncompressed image?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2765012 for an attempt to create a theoretical maximum, and the discussion below for more insight.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. JPG compression depends on quality settings, and the content of the image. A single solid color "tile" will compress far better than a "busy" image.

E.g. a solid white 800x600 image saved in [The Gimp](http://gimp.org) at 85% quality is a 3,155 bytes .jpg file. Filling that same 800x600 image with the RGB noise filter produces a 134,935 byte .jpg.